# How can i make a form using django.contrib.comments.forms?

Tags: python, django, forms

This is the form file of django.contrib.comments.forms:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/comments/forms.py

I need to create an object of that form and use it in template. I don't want to make html form object manually in templates, I want to reuse that contrib.comments.forms.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. May be need to modify this code depending on how do you want to process form data.

```
from django.contrib.comments.forms import CommentForm

# views.py
dev my_view(request):
    my_obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
    form = CommentForm(my_obj)
    return render(request, 'comment-template.html', {'form': form})

# comment_template.html
<form action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="post">
    {% csrf token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: CommentForm needs object in `__init__`. MyObject is any your model, to which comments would be assigned.

Comment: But if you see this code, https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/comments/forms.py#L182 , the parameter is not a model, rather `CommentDetailsForm` class

Comment: It's not a parameter, it's base class. `CommentSecurityForm` is in turn base class for `CommentDetailsForm`, and `CommentSecurityForm` has `__init__` method with `target_object` argument.